# Cálculo em um valor específico de um dataframe?

Tags: r, data.frame

Possuindo esse conjunto de dados:

```
   Índice                Produto  Classificação Comum Quilo
1       2          ABACAXI HAVAI       A GRAUDO  3,32   2,2
2       3          ABACAXI HAVAI        B MEDIO  2,81   1,8
3       4          ABACAXI HAVAI        C MIUDO  2,21   1,4
4       5            BANANA MACA              -   4,5     1
5       6        BANANA PRATA MG              -  3,13     1
```

Desejo multiplicar alguns valores da coluna comum por uma constante, por exemplo, os 3 valores de abacaxi quero multiplicar por 100, ficando assim:

```
   Índice                Produto  Classificação Comum Quilo
1       2          ABACAXI HAVAI       A GRAUDO   332   2,2
2       3          ABACAXI HAVAI        B MEDIO   281   1,8
3       4          ABACAXI HAVAI        C MIUDO   221   1,4
4       5            BANANA MACA              -   4,5     1
5       6        BANANA PRATA MG              -  3,13     1
```

Como posso fazer isso pelo R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha primeira providência aqui é substituir as vírgulas por pontos. Por exemplo, o `R` não considera 1,54 um número. Isto é uma string para o programa. Portanto, é necessário fazer este primeiro passo. A função `gsub` resolve este problema em uma linha:

```
df$Comun <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", df$Comun))
```

Ali em cima estou pedindo pra o `R` substituir todas as vírgulas por pontos (que devem ser representados por `\\.` porque são caracteres especiais) na coluna `Comun` do data frame `df`.

Agora é possível fazer a multiplicação desejada. Basta selecionar as linhas que interessam no data frame, multiplicar a coluna correspondente por 3 e substituir no data frame original:

```
df[df$Produto=="ABACAXI HAVAI", "Comun"]*100
```

No comando acima estou escolhendo as linhas com `ABACAXI HAVAI` na coluna produto `Produto`. Além disso, precisei especificar a coluna `Comun` para indicar onde estavam os valores numéricos que me interessavam. Com estes valores selecionados, bastou multiplicá-los por 100 e o resultado estará pronto.

---

Tentei resolver este problema usando funções do pacote `dplyr`, mas estava ficando complicado demais e desisti.

Comment: Se eu quiser adicionar outros produtos na multiplicação é só colocar um &? Ex: df[df$Produto=="ABACAXI HAVAI" & "BANANA MACA", "Comun"]*100

Comment: Marcus, outro ponto, eu quero que esse novo valor após a multiplicação substitua o valor antigo

Comment: A resposta para a primeira pergunta é não. Precisa colocar `|` (ou) para escolher as linhas com dois ou mais produtos. A resposta para a segunda pergunta é `df[df$Produto=="ABACAXI HAVAI", "Comun"]
 <- df[df$Produto=="ABACAXI HAVAI", "Comun"]*100`.

Answer (score 0):

Há várias formas de se manipular os valores de uma coluna de um data.frame. Com as funções base do R, supondo que seu data.frame se chame `df`, no seu caso basta fazer:

```
df$Comum <- df$Comum*100
```

Se você quiser multiplicar apenas a linha com "ABACAXI HAVAI":

```
df$Comum[df$Produto == "ABACAXI HAVAI"] <- df$Comum[df$Produto == "ABACAXI HAVAI"]*100
```

Se você quiser filtrar mais linhas use `%in%`:

```
   df$Comum[df$Produto %in% c("ABACAXI HAVAI","BANANA MACA")] <- df$Comum[df$Produto %in% c("ABACAXI HAVAI","BANANA MACA")]*100
```

Dando um exemplo com a base `mtcars` que já vem no R:

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Vamos multiplicar a coluna `mpg` por 3:

```
mtcars$mpg <- mtcars$mpg*3
head(mtcars)
                  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         63.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     63.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        68.4   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    64.2   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 56.1   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           54.3   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Multiplicando apenas com linhas `cyl == 6`:

```
 mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == 6] <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == 6]*3
```

Também é possível fazer a mesma coisa com a função `mutate()` do pacote `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate(mpg = mpg*3)
```

Comment: Meu objetivo é multiplicar um único ou somente alguns valores do data.frame, não a coluna toda

Comment: @DaniloImbimbo ok, basta selecionar as linhas que você quer, vou incluir na resposa